# Why does the type-hinting for enum show an error on VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, vscode-python

I've run into an issue where the expected return type (`Enum`) and the actual return type do not match, even though they should.

The weird thing is that depending on the way that I write the return statement, the results are different.

The following picture explains this better:

[image: screenshot of VS Code with line marked with error]

The error message is:

> "Expression of type "auto" cannot be assigned to return type "PaymentValidationStatus" "auto" is incompatible with "PaymentValidationStatus"Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)"

The code is:

```
class PaymentValidationStatus(Enum):
    ORDER_NOT_FOUND = auto()
    ALREADY_PAID = auto()
    PAYMENT_AMOUNT_DOEST_NOT_MATCH_ORDER_PRICE = auto()
    COULD_NOT_PAY_ORDER = auto()
    PAYMENT_OK = auto()


def some() -> PaymentValidationStatus:
    return PaymentValidationStatus["PAYMENT_OK"]


def some2() -> PaymentValidationStatus:
    return PaymentValidationStatus.PAYMENT_OK
```

The version of vscode, python and python extension are:

- VSCode: 1.67 (MacOS)
- Python: 3.10
- Python extension: v2022.6.0

**Update:**

I have tried this code in a clean project and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I copy-pasted that exact same code and cannot reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X08gd.png. I have VS Code 1.66.2 with the official [Microsoft's Python for VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and with pylance + flake8 + mypy all enabled (with pylance on strict checking mode). I see no errors on the Problems tab.

Comment: @Gino Mempin But there is no red wavy line in your updated picture

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Yes, because as I said [in my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131501/why-does-the-type-hinting-for-enum-show-an-error-on-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment127454796_72131501), I cannot reproduce the error/issue that the OP is raising. I copied the posted code as-is, then I am showing in my picture that I cannot reproduce any red wavy lines.

Comment: To confirm, is `Enum` the same [`Enum` from the `enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum)?

Comment: @GinoMempin, yes it's the same module.

Comment: @joel, the error message is this "Expression of type "auto" cannot be assigned to return type "PaymentValidationStatus"
  "auto" is incompatible with "PaymentValidationStatus"Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)"